# Setting folder for dependencies in C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a C# project with a bunch of dependencies, but I want to store them in another folder from where the executable is.

For example

```
WTEngine/
/bin
--Dependencies go here
/otherfolder
WTEngine.exe
```

How do I do that?  I move them and the executable can't find them anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer for ASP.NET addresses the same issue, and most of the answers can be effectively ported to a desktop executable: [How do I reference assemblies outside the bin folder in an ASP.net application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206138/how-do-i-reference-assemblies-outside-the-bin-folder-in-an-asp-net-application)

Also see [How do I change the lookup path for .NET libraries referenced via #using in Managed C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503266/how-do-i-change-the-lookup-path-for-net-libraries-referenced-via-using-in-mana)

Answer (score 0):

The .NET dependencies are loaded automatically from two places:

- GAC (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache)
- the current path of the executing assembly (your exe)

You cannot move the dependencies in another folder and have them loaded automatically.

If you decide to load the assemblies manually, check out this question:

[How to Load an Assembly to AppDomain with all references recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658498/how-to-load-assembly-to-appdomain-with-all-references-recursively)